# Light grays as white on monitor

Tags: display, f.lux

Light gray colors appear as white on my monitor.

Like #f5f5f5 appears as #ffffff.

Many website forms use light grays for outlines which makes it hard to see the inputs.

But in the night time when [Flux](https://justgetflux.com/) is running I can see the outlines.

I've tried a bunch of different brightness / contrast combinations but I can never see these light grays.

Maybe the monitor is just too bright.

I'm using HDMI and not DisplayPort because right now I'm using the onboard graphics which doesn't have DisplayPort connection.

Could this be because I'm using HDMI and not DisplayPort?

Comment: You can run f.lux with the night settings during the day. I do exactly this as I don't like the day settings (except when watching movies - then I disable f.lux or put it movie mode).

Comment: Have you tried this approach? https://superuser.com/a/1214435/442991