# Yellow and gray blend with white on a remote monitor connected with a HDMI-VGA adapter

Tags: hdmi, xorg, colors, external-display, xrandr

The problem is that yellow and gray are hardly visible on my remote monitor. For example when I open StackOverflow I cannot see the yellow background of quote blocks and the gray background of code blocks. They just blend with the white background.

How can I fix the way colors are displayed on the second monitor?

## Details

- The remote monitor is Samsung 2043NW and it has only an VGA port.
- I've experienced this behavior on two different machines: Lenovo Yoga 3 14 and Dell XPS 17 L702X. They were connected using the same HDMI-VGA adapter.
- Colors are OK when I connect the monitor to Lenovo ThinkPad X230 to its VGA port.
- I've tried changing the color settings on both the monitor itself and with software tools like `xbrightness`, `xgamma` and so on. It didn't work although it looks like a problem with brightness or an invalid gamma calibration.
- I've experienced this on both FreeBSD (10.3, 11) and Ubuntu (17.04).
- I've already tried a few different adapters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### tl;dr

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Limited 16:235"
```

---

### Detailed answer

The problem was with the X server. The idea came from [this Arch Linux Wiki article about `xrandr`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr#Full_RGB_in_HDM).

They suggest there to run:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"
```

in order to fix colors. It didn't work but I decided to see other options I can change with `--set`.

On Ubuntu 17.04 `xrandr --prop` returns:

```
HDMI-1 connected 1050x1680+1920+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 459mm x 296mm
        [... some uninteresting properties ...]

        Broadcast RGB: Automatic
                supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235

        [... some uninteresting properties ...]
```

It turns out that

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Limited 16:235"
```

fixed the issue and now all the colors are distinguishable.